# Node javascript require js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just want to load the content of a js file into my variable ! but it's returning me an object ? how can i achieve that ?

**server.js**

```
const file = require("./server/file.js");
ctx.body = `${file}`; // Should return "(function () { console.log("ok");})";
```

**//file.js**

```
(function () {
  console.log("ok");
});
```

Comment: file.js does not export anything. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use file reader for this, check out this documentation [NodeJs website](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths)

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./server/file.js', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    const fileContent = data;
    console.log(fileContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any CommonJS module will export the value of `module.exports` which defaults to being an empty object (i.e. what you are seeing).

Your module doesn't explicitly export anything.

It has a function expression that you do *nothing* with (you don't call it, you don't assign it anywhere, you don't pass it anywhere: it is completely pointless).

If you want to export the function then you need to do so explicitly.

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("ok");
}

module.exports = myFunction;
```

Comment: i tried that but how can i trigger it on document load directly ? i want something like this const file = (function () {
  console.log("ok");
});

module.exports = file;

Comment: @totobolocolo — Node.js doesn't have documents, so that doesn't make any sense.